# DRF docs - getting serializers dynamically

Tags: django-rest-framework, documentation

I have a viewset which uses different serializers for different HTTP methods (and possibly even for different users). DRF docs says this:

```
To be compatible with this behaviour methods (such as get_serializer or
get_serializer_class etc.) which inspect self.request or, particularly, 
self.request.user may need to be adjusted to handle this case.
```

Can anyone provide me an example of the "adjustment to handle this case"?

Say I have a viewset which is using serializer `A` for get method for admins, serializer `B` for get method for all other users and serializer `C` for all other methods. How to specify this so that the documentation understands this? I am using the builtin one.

My `urls.py`:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('test', SampleViewset, base_name="test")

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('docs/', include_docs_urls(title='My API title', public=True)),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Minimal example**
`models.py`

```
class SampleModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = SampleModel


class SampleSerializerCreate(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    age = serializers.IntegerField(max_value=20)

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = SampleModel
```

`views.py`

```
class SampleViewset(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SampleSerializer
    queryset = SampleModel.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action=='create':
            return SampleSerializerCreate
        return SampleSerializer
```

Here I used a logic that, while creation of `SampleModel`, the `age` attribute should not exceed a max_value of 20.

**Update-1**

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'sample', SampleViewset)
urlpatterns = [
                  path('docs/', include_docs_urls(title='My API title', public=True, patterns=router.urls)),

              ] + router.urls
```

Comment: This snippet says `'NoneType' object is not callable`.

Comment: can you show the traceback? (edit the question and add)

Comment: Added a complete minimal example

Comment: still the same error. Just to ensure I am doing it right, I do `http://example.com/docs/` and in my urlpatterns, I have `path('docs/', include_docs_urls(title='My API title', public=True))`

Comment: please add your urls.py

Comment: anyway, I added an example urls.py file. pls do follow that

Comment: where do I find the documentation when I use your example urls.py?

Comment: I mean where do I find the generated documentation of my API, not the documentation of DRF routers :). In my urls which I just included, it is `/docs/`, but I do not see a way how to get there from yours.

Comment: Actually it's depends on your *relative url path*. But the end point will be `/sample/`

Comment: What I see on `/sample/` is this: https://ibb.co/juzUVp , however what I want to see is something like this: https://ibb.co/esOjwU

Comment: This is how DRF behave. I have no idea how can we convert to that *required format**.

Comment: This is what `path('docs/', include_docs_urls(title='My API title', public=True))` line does along with `coreapi` package installed. Then, you can access `/docs/` where you find documentation of your API.

Comment: add `patterns` parameter to `include_docs_urls()` , (updated the answer)

Comment: Fine, this works, thanks. Any ideas about the second part of the question, differentiating the serializer based on the user? I just found out that at the time of generating the docs, `request` is None and thus it does not suffice to just write an if in the `get_serializer_class` method. I really do not want to use an external tool like Doxygen...

Comment: This might work, `if self.action=='create':` to `if self.request.user.id==id_of_particular_user:`

Comment: `self.request` is None, therefore it says `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'`